# Sum of two angles

Tags: python, math, geometry, trigonometry

1. We have an angle in radians, from -PI to +PI
2. We have an offset (0.2rad for instance)

How can I add this offset to an angle and get a resulting value which should also be from -PI to PI ? Feeling a lil' stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `%`:

```
angle = (angle + 0.2 + pi) % (2*pi) - pi
```

Comment: That's not `%`, that's `%` and like three other things. :) The key to that code snippet, @phantasm, is that you're taking a number in the `[-pi,pi]` range and adding `pi` so that it's now in the range `[0,2*pi]` and is `pi` greater than it was. Then you do the addition and the modulus, to get the result in the `[0,2*pi]` range (still with an extra `pi`). Finally, you subtract out the extra `pi`, leaving you with the correct result in the correct range.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger The extra `pi` is in there as a ploy to end up with an origin-centered range without an extra conditional. The alternative (arguably more correct) approach would be `if angle > pi: angle -= 2*pi` afterwards, but that's more characters.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger the `+pi` and `-pi` require each other, but yes.

Comment: @Sneftel Yeah, I understood that they were reciprocal but was thinking that `(x + m) % (2*m)` was equivalent to `x % (2*m)` in this situation. Forget it.

Comment: If Sneftel's explanation were in Daniel's answer it'd be worth an extra up-vote or two. :)

Comment: In the case where the angle is at the lower end of the interval and the offset is negative, this code will probably fail. `angle=-3.1`, `offset=-0.2` so `angle+offset+pi` is still negative, the modulo operation leaves this invariant since the rounded-to-zero quotient is 0, restoring the angle gives a result smaller than `-pi`. --> Use a higher period, `(angle+offset+3*pi)%(2*pi) - pi`.